# how to check a string for specific conditions in C++

Tags: c++, string, substring

following snippet shows a very small part of my current output:

```
1464:       ebfffe4d        bl      da0 <memcpy@plt>
14bc:       ebfffe37        bl      da0 <memcpy@plt>
```

every line from the output refers to a string. What I want to archieve is, that in this
case only memcpy@plt will be printed once. When a string contains "bl" then the name
within <...> should be printed and only once printed, since the name within <...> is the same
in both cases. Is there a way to get this?
My current code looks as follows:

```
class CallFunction {
    private:
        vector<string> content;
    public:
        CallFunction(vector<string> content) {
            this->content = content;
        }
        void print() {
            for(string line: content) {
                if(line.find("bl") != std::string::npos
                && line.find("<") != std::string::npos) {
                    cout << line << endl;
                }
            }
        }
};

int main() {
    string fileName = "libndkmod.s";
    vector<string> content = readFile(fileName);
    CallFunction cf = CallFunction(content);
    cf.print();
}
```

Thanks in advance and kind regards!

Comment: You could store the name in a set, and print the line only if the name isn't int the set.

Comment: Or store them in a set and then just print the whole set.

Comment: Will multiple occurrences of a name be in cosecutive lines? Then you do not need a set, just a single variable of the currents streak name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a `unordered_set` to deduplicate the substring, if the same substring has already been printed, then skip it.

This step can be extracted into a single method to follow the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), which is more natural than process the duplication in `print` function, this work is left for you.

We use `unordered_set` instead of `std::set` since `unordered_set` will be quicker to search.

I have changed the for loop from `for(string line: content)` into `for(const string& line: content)`, then we avoid a copy of the original string, to improve the performance. Basically, we will prefer to use `for(const auto& item:...)` for objects except primitive types to avoid a copy.

We store `string_view` which is introduced in c++17 to avoid copy the sub-string, it will save memory since we avoid unnecessarily copy.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class CallFunction {
 private:
  vector<string> content;

 public:
  CallFunction(vector<string> content) { this->content = content; }
  void print() {
    std::unordered_set<std::string_view> mem;
    for (const string& line : content) {
      auto left_pos = line.find("bl");
      auto right_pos = line.find(">");
      if (left_pos != std::string::npos && right_pos != std::string::npos) {
        std::string_view sub_view = {&line.front() + left_pos,
                                     right_pos - left_pos + 1};
        if (mem.count(sub_view)) continue;
        mem.insert(sub_view);
        cout << line << endl;
      }
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  string fileName = "libndkmod.s";
  vector<string> content = {
      "1464:       ebfffe4d        bl      da0 <memcpy@plt>",
      "14bc:       ebfffe37        bl      da0 <memcpy@plt>",
      "14bc:       ebfffe37        bl      da0 <memcmp@plt>"};
  CallFunction cf = CallFunction(content);
  cf.print();
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hvdsxWYfP)